# getIntent().getSerializableExtra is null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I have a `POJO` class implements `Serializable`
and I want to transfer an object of this class to another `activity` with a help `Intent` and `Bundle`.
I checked the object before the transfer, it is not null. (Correctly get one of attributes)

**put:**

```
private void onFriendClick(FriendHolder holder, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
        Bundle extra = new Bundle();
        extra.putSerializable(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON,  friendList.get(position));
        intent.putExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON, extra);
        Log.e("onFriendClick", String.valueOf(friendList.get(position).getName()));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**get from another activity:**

```
 private void setupProfile() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            profile = (ProfileDTO) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON);
            Log.e("onFriendClick", String.valueOf(profile.getName()));//NPE this
        } else profile = user.getProfile();
    }
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String
>   ru.techmas.getmeet.api.models.ProfileDTO.getName()' on a null object
>   reference
>                         at ru.techmas.getmeet.activities.ProfileActivity.setupJsonProfile(ProfileActivity.java:103)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a `Bundle`.
Try doing:

```
private void onFriendClick(FriendHolder holder, int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON,  friendList.get(position));
    Log.e("onFriendClick", String.valueOf(friendList.get(position).getName()));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

private void setupProfile() {
    if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON) != null) {
        profile = (ProfileDTO) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON); 
        Log.e("onFriendClick", String.valueOf(profile.getName()));//NPE this
    } else {
        profile = user.getProfile();
    }
}
```

---

But if still want to use the `Bundle`, you should replace in the code that you posted:

```
profile = (ProfileDTO) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON);
```

By:

```
profile = (ProfileDTO) extras.getSerializableExtra(Consts.KEY_USER_JSON);
```